# Xamarin.iOS: Loading images dynamically from Url fails on device

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin.iOS application where I use MVVMCross. My issue is with a tableview where images are loaded dynamically from an api.

When I run the application in the simulator, everything is OK, but when I run it from the device, the images are gone. The reference to an image is in this format:

`https://example.com/api/File/a16cf18a-018a-4bb8-97fd-e8d4692e3e52`

I have a tableview with a MvxTableViewCell and I set the binding like this:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ItemCell, ItemViewModel>();
set.Bind(ItemImage).To(vm => vm.ImageUrl);
```

Comment: You should check out DownloadCache plugin and MvxImage view: https://mvvmcross.com/docs/downloadcache

Comment: I already use MvxImage, but without downloadcache, I will check it out. Thank you for the tip.